# How to make a code-generated mesh interact with a rigidbody?

Tags: unity, physics, procedural-generation, mesh, rigidbody

I'm using a sphere and an empty game object that generates a mesh upon playing/starting.

On the mesh, I place a `Mesh Collider` component with `None` for the "Material" and "Mesh" fields and a `RigidBody` with "kinematic" checked. Then when I place a `Rigidbody` on the sphere, it just falls through it.

I'm not sure what I'm missing so that the sphere will fall and land on the mesh and treat it like another object like a plane for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use your code created `Mesh` with the collider you need to assign it to be used by the `MeshCollider` and `MeshFilter` component. Then turn `MeshCollider.convex` to `false` in the `FixedUpdate()` function.

You may have `convex` set to `false` in the `MeshCollider` component but when I tried to collide my mesh with a physics object (Sphere) then it would not work. I'm not sure why but when I flipped `convex` between true and false before the collision occurs it would work. The only way to avoid doing this is to do it as I explain above and show below.

I hope someone who knows Unity better than I can explain what is going on exactly but this  is how I made it work.

Example of the assignments in your `Start()` function, in this case I'll call it `mesh` and will have this:

```
MeshCollider collider;
void Start()
{
        mesh = new Mesh();
        // do your mesh setup here or call a method that does it

        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
        collider = GetComponent<MeshCollider>();
        collider.sharedMesh = mesh;
}

void FixedUpdate() {
        collider.convex = false;
}
```